# Timetabling using multiobjective Genetic Algorithms based on Dynamic Gene Spaces

Tags: python

you can find the code on the last pages of the pdf file
https://www.diegopeluffo.com/Theses/2022_MastersThesis_MartinVelez.pdf

the whole code is like this

```
from re import A
from sql import *
import random
import copy
import numpy as np
from pygad import GA
from collections import Counter



pel=56
mutation_num_genes=20
SYNC=get_materia_s_pel(pel) #indeces materias

HORARIO_SYNC=get_horario_s(pel)
DATOS_SYNC=get_datos_s_pel(pel)
INFO_SYNC=get_info_s_pel(pel)
DOCENTE_SYNC=get_doc_s_pel(pel)
MAT_AULAS_HOURS_CONTRAINT=[]
MAT_DOC_CONTRAINT=[]

SHAPE=(SYNC['OFG_NUMERO'].size,5)

CONSTRAINT=[]
DURATION=[]

INVERVALOS_DIAS={}
HORARIO_SYNC.HORAFINAL = HORARIO_SYNC.HORAFINAL -1
HORARIO_SYNC.HORAINICIAL = HORARIO_SYNC.HORAINICIAL -1
HORARIO_SYNC.DIADESDE = HORARIO_SYNC.DIADESDE -1
HORARIO_SYNC.DIAHASTA = HORARIO_SYNC.DIAHASTA -1
acc=0

MAX_HORAS=24

def non_consecutive_combinator(rnge, r, prev=[]):
    if r == 0:
        yield prev

    else:
        for i, item in enumerate(rnge):
            for next_comb in non_consecutive_combinator(rnge[i+2:], r-1, prev+[item]):
                yield next_comb



for dia,intervalo in enumerate(range(0,7)):
    INVERVALOS_DIAS[dia]=list(range(acc,acc+15))
    acc=acc+MAX_HORAS

def clean_hours(int_list,length):
    return [int_list[i] for i in range(0, len(int_list))
            if sum(np.diff(int_list[i:i+length]))==length-1]
def check_option(x,w):
    c=0
    if (x[0]==0 and x[-1]==6):
        return False
    for i in x:
        if w[i]==0.:
            return False
        if w[i]==0.5:
            c+=1
    if c>1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
def seleccion_horario(dias,horas,domain):
    list_days=map(split_day_week,domain)
    b_hour,b_day,c=-1,0,0
    days_count=np.zeros((7))
    days={0:[],1:[],2:[],3:[],4:[],5:[],6:[]}
    for day,hour in list_days:
        hour=join_day_week(day,hour)
        days[day].append(hour)
        if b_hour+1==hour and b_day==day:
            c+=1
        else:
            c=1
        b_hour,b_day=hour,day
        if c>days_count[day]:
            days_count[day]=c
    max_hours=list(filter(lambda x:x>=max(horas),days_count))
    result,selected_day=False,None
    if len(max_hours)>=horas.count(max(horas)) and \
        len(list(filter(lambda x:x>=min(horas),days_count)))-len(max_hours)>=1 \
        or len(max_hours)>=dias:
        result=True

    if result:
        if dias<4:
            max_hours=(days_count>=max(horas)).astype(int)
            prob_hours=max_hours+(max_hours-(days_count>=min(horas)
                                             ).astype(int)==-1).astype(int)*0.5
            desicion=non_consecutive_combinator([0,1,2,3,4,5,6], dias)
            days_list=list(filter(lambda x: check_option(x,prob_hours),desicion))

            if days_list:
                selected_day=random.choice(days_list)
                selected_day=list(filter(lambda x:prob_hours[x]==1,selected_day))+\
                    list(filter(lambda x:prob_hours[x]==0.5,selected_day))
        if not selected_day:
            options=np.where(days_count>=max(horas))[0]
            selected_day=random.sample(list(options),dias-1)
            options_min=list(set(np.where(days_count>=min(horas))[0])
                             -set(selected_day))
            selected_day=selected_day+[random.choice(options_min)]



        horario=[]
        for i,day in enumerate(selected_day):
            horario.append(random.choice(clean_hours(days[day],horas[i])))
        if horario:
            return horario

    return [-666]

def get_horas_dias(t_horas):
    if t_horas<=3:
        dias=1
        horas=[t_horas]
    elif t_horas==4:
        dias=2
        horas=[2,2]
    elif t_horas==5:
        dias=2
        horas=[3,2]
    elif t_horas==6:
        dias=2
        horas=[3,3]
    elif t_horas==7:
        dias=3
        horas=[3,2,2]
    elif t_horas==8:
        dias=3
        horas=[3,3,2]
    elif t_horas==9:
        dias=3
        horas=[3,3,3]
    elif t_horas==11:
        dias=4
        horas=[3,3,3,2]
    elif t_horas==12:
        dias=4
        horas=[3,3,3,3]
    elif t_horas==13:
        dias=5
        horas=[3,3,3,3,1]
    elif t_horas==14:
        dias=5
        horas=[3,3,3,3,2]
    elif t_horas==15:
        dias=5
        horas=[3,3,3,3,3]
    return dias,horas
def obtener_intervalos(ofg_numero,schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,schedule_doc,limit=0):
    info=INFO_SYNC.loc[INFO_SYNC['OFG_NUMERO']==ofg_numero][
        ['CAR_CODIGO','MAA_NIVEL']].drop_duplicates()[limit:]
    domain=[]
    domain_2=[]
    for row, elem in info.iterrows():
        domain=domain+schedule_lvl.get(str(elem.CAR_CODIGO)+'-'+str(elem.MAA_NIVEL),[])
    docente=get_docente(ofg_numero)
    if docente:
        domain=domain+schedule_doc.get(docente,[])
    return domain,domain_2
def set_list(dic,codigo,lista):




    if codigo in dic:
        dic[codigo]+=lista
    else:
        dic[codigo]=lista

def save_best_solution_sync(data):
    data[data<-999]=data[data<-999]/1000
    data[data<0]=-1*data[data<0]
    datos=[]
    for index,row in SYNC.iterrows():

            dias,horas=get_horas_dias(row.DID_HORAS_SINCRONICAS)
            for num_dia,i in enumerate(filter(lambda x: x>0,horas)):
                info=DATOS_SYNC.loc[DATOS_SYNC['OFG_NUMERO']==row.OFG_NUMERO]
                dia,hora=split_day_week(data[index][num_dia])
                for row2,values in info.iterrows():
                    for time in range(hora+1,hora+i+1):
                        datos.append({'OFG_NUMERO':int(values.OFG_NUMERO),
                        'CAR_CODIGO':int(values.CAR_CODIGO),
                        'MAA_NIVEL':int(values.MAA_NIVEL)
                        ,'HDD_DIA':int(dia+1),
                        'HDD_HORA_INICIAL':int(time),
                        'HDD_HORA_FINAL':int(time+1),
                        'FAC_CODIGO':int(values.FAC_CODIGO),
                        'PRA_NUMERO':int(values.PRA_NUMERO),
                        'CAM_CODIGO':int(values.CAM_CODIGO),
                        'SED_CODIGO':int(values.SED_CODIGO),
                        'MAT_CODIGO':int(values.MAT_CODIGO[0]),'PEL_CODIGO':pel,
                        'DOCENTE_AUTOR':int(values.DOCENTE_AUTOR)
                        if not np.isnan(values.DOCENTE_AUTOR) else 0,
                        'DID_CODIGO':int(values.DID_CODIGO)})
    return pd.DataFrame(datos)
def set_horarios(ofg_numero,horas,schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,schedule_ofg,schedule_doc):
    info=INFO_SYNC.loc[INFO_SYNC['OFG_NUMERO']==ofg_numero][['CAR_CODIGO','MAA_NIVEL']].drop_duplicates()
    docente=get_docente(ofg_numero)
    if docente:
        set_list(schedule_doc,docente,horas.copy())
    set_list(schedule_ofg,str(ofg_numero),horas.copy())
    for row, elem in info.iterrows():
        set_list(schedule_lvl,str(elem.CAR_CODIGO)+'-'+str(elem.MAA_NIVEL),horas.copy())

        #set_list(schedule_carr,str(elem.CAR_CODIGO),horas)



def get_probability(todos,values_to_select_from):
    freq=[todos.count(i) for i in values_to_select_from]
    freq=max(freq)-np.array(freq)
    if sum(freq)!=0:
        freq=freq/sum(freq)
    return freq

def get_docente(ofg_numero):
    docente=DOCENTE_SYNC[DOCENTE_SYNC['OFG_NUMERO']==ofg_numero]
    if not docente.empty:
        docente=docente.iloc[0]['DOCENTE_AUTOR']
        if not np.isnan(docente):
            return str(int(docente))






    return False
def remove_domains(ofg_numero,schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,
                   schedule_doc,dias,horas,intv2,domain):
    c=0
    docente=get_docente(ofg_numero)
    aux_domain=domain.copy()
    horario=None
    if docente:
        tmp_domain=schedule_doc.get(docente,[])
        horas_disponibles2=intv2 - set(tmp_domain)
        horario=seleccion_horario(dias,horas,horas_disponibles2)
    else:
        tmp_domain=[]
    if -666 not in horario:
        return True,False,horario
    if not tmp_domain:
        while(tmp_domain!=domain):
            c=c + 1
            domain,_=obtener_intervalos(ofg_numero,schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,
                                         schedule_doc,c)
            if domain != aux_domain:
                horas_disponibles2=intv2 - set(domain)
                horario=seleccion_horario(dias,horas,horas_disponibles2)
                aux_domain=domain.copy()
            if -666 not in horario:
                return True,False,horario
    else:
        return False, True, horario
def select_day(ofg_numero,t_horas,schedule_ofg,schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,schedule_doc):
    dias,horas=get_horas_dias(t_horas)
    domain,_=obtener_intervalos(ofg_numero,schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,schedule_doc)
    intv_completo=set(np.array([INVERVALOS_DIAS[i]
                                for i in INVERVALOS_DIAS]).flatten())
    intv_param=set(intervalo_dias(ofg_numero))
    horas_disponibles_todo=intv_completo - set(domain) #horas disponibles sin tomar encuenta la parametrizacion
    horas_disponibles_param=intv_param - set(domain) #horas disponibles sin tomar en cuenta la parametrizacion
    penalizar_no_param=False
    penalizar_cruze_nivel=False
    horario=seleccion_horario(dias,horas,horas_disponibles_param)
    if -666 in horario:
        horario=seleccion_horario(dias,horas,horas_disponibles_todo) #toma encuenta la parametrizacion y salto de dias
        penalizar_no_param=True
    #Admite cruzes de horarios
    if -666 in horario:
        penalizar_cruze_nivel,penalizar_no_param,horario=remove_domains(
            ofg_numero,schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,schedule_doc,dias,
            horas,intv_completo,domain)

    if -666 not in horario:
        for x,hora_selecionada in enumerate(np.absolute(horario)):
            horas_horario=range(hora_selecionada,hora_selecionada+horas[x])
            set_horarios(ofg_numero,list(horas_horario),schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,schedule_ofg, schedule_doc)
        if penalizar_no_param:
            horario=list(-1*np.array(horario)) #se detectica que no hizo uso de la parametrizacion
        if penalizar_cruze_nivel:
            horario=list(np.array(horario)) #se detectica que no hizo uso de la parametrizacion

    return horario




def intervalo_dias(ofg_numero):
    """
    Busca obtiene el conjunto de intervalos paramatrizados
    """
    intervalo=[]
    horarios_busqueda=HORARIO_SYNC[HORARIO_SYNC['OFG_NUMERO']==ofg_numero]
    for row,horario_busqueda in horarios_busqueda.iterrows():
        inicio=horario_busqueda['DIADESDE']
        fin=horario_busqueda['DIAHASTA']
        hora_ini=horario_busqueda['HORAINICIAL']
        hora_fin=horario_busqueda['HORAFINAL']
        for dia in range(inicio,fin+1):
            intervalo+=list(range(hora_ini+(dia*MAX_HORAS),(dia*MAX_HORAS)+hora_fin))
    return intervalo

def join_day_week(day,hour):
    return day*MAX_HORAS+hour
def split_day_week(value):
    day=value//MAX_HORAS
    time=value%MAX_HORAS
    return int(day),int(time)

def fitness_func(solution, solution_idx):
    actual_populations=solution.reshape(*SHAPE)
    return validate_data(actual_populations)

def check_docente(did_horas_sincronicas,ofg_numero,schedule_doc,schedule_lvl,pobla):
    _,horas=get_horas_dias(did_horas_sincronicas)
    docente=get_docente(ofg_numero)
    horario_docente=schedule_doc.get(docente,[])
    info=INFO_SYNC.loc[INFO_SYNC['OFG_NUMERO']==ofg_numero][['CAR_CODIGO','MAA_NIVEL']].drop_duplicates()
    lista_cruzes_lvl=[]
    for row, elem in info.iterrows():
        lista_cruzes_lvl=lista_cruzes_lvl+\
            schedule_lvl.get(str(elem.CAR_CODIGO)+'-'+str(elem.MAA_NIVEL),[])
    for i, hora in enumerate(horas):
        horario=list(range(int(pobla[i]),int(pobla[i])+hora))
        for j in horario:
            if j in horario_docente:
                return True
            if j in lista_cruzes_lvl:
                return True
    return False
def set_data(did_horas_sincronicas,ofg_numero,schedule_lvl,
             schedule_carr,schedule_ofg, schedule_doc,pobla):
    _,horas=get_horas_dias(did_horas_sincronicas)
    for i, hora in enumerate(horas):
        horario=list(range(int(pobla[i]),int(pobla[i])+hora))
        set_horarios(ofg_numero,horario,schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,
                     schedule_ofg, schedule_doc)

def get_cruzes_docente(did_horas_sincronicas,schedule_doc,pobla,docente):
    _,horas=get_horas_dias(did_horas_sincronicas)
    for i, hora in enumerate(horas):
        horario=list(range(int(pobla[i]),int(pobla[i])+hora))
        for j in horas:
            if j in schedule_doc[docente]:



                return -10000
def validate_data(actual_populations):
    mal_horario=np.where((np.sum(actual_populations,axis=1)<-1)&(np.sum(actual_populations,axis=1)>-1000))[0]
    c_data= save_best_solution_sync(actual_populations.copy())
    prof_mal=-1000000 *len(c_data[['HDD_HORA_INICIAL','HDD_DIA','DOCENTE_AUTOR',
                                'OFG_NUMERO']].drop_duplicates().groupby(
                                ['DOCENTE_AUTOR','HDD_HORA_INICIAL','HDD_DIA'])
                                .filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)['OFG_NUMERO']
                                .drop_duplicates().values)
    ofgs=c_data[['OFG_NUMERO','CAR_CODIGO','MAA_NIVEL',
                 'HDD_HORA_INICIAL','HDD_DIA']].drop_duplicates().groupby(
    ['CAR_CODIGO','MAA_NIVEL','HDD_DIA','HDD_HORA_INICIAL']
    ).filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)['OFG_NUMERO'].drop_duplicates()
    ofgs_day_bad=c_data[c_data['HDD_DIA']>7]['OFG_NUMERO'].values
    index=list(SYNC.index[SYNC.OFG_NUMERO.isin(ofgs)].values)
    actual_populations[index]=-1*actual_populations[index]
    index=list(SYNC.index[SYNC.OFG_NUMERO.isin(ofgs_day_bad)].values)
    if index:
        actual_populations[index][0]=-666
    return -len(np.where(np.any(actual_populations==-666,axis=1))[0]
                )*1000000 -SYNC.loc[mal_horario]['CUPO_SUBGRUPO'].sum()\
        -100*SYNC[SYNC.OFG_NUMERO.isin(set(ofgs))].CUPO_SUBGRUPO.sum()+prof_mal-len(
            index)*100000




def start_random_population():
    population=np.zeros(SHAPE)
    create_schedule(population,flag=True)
    return population

def create_schedule(actual_populations,flag=False):
    schedule_ofg={}
    schedule_carr={}
    schedule_lvl={}
    schedule_doc={}

    mutation_indices = random.sample(list(range(0, SHAPE[0])), mutation_num_genes)
    for index,row in SYNC.iterrows():
        chk_docente=check_docente(row.DID_HORAS_SINCRONICAS,row.OFG_NUMERO,
                    schedule_doc,schedule_lvl,np.absolute(actual_populations[index]))
        if flag or index in mutation_indices or np.any(actual_populations[index] <0) \
            or chk_docente:
            result_days=select_day(row.OFG_NUMERO,row.DID_HORAS_SINCRONICAS,
                        schedule_ofg,schedule_lvl,schedule_carr,schedule_doc)
            for i,val in enumerate(result_days):
                actual_populations[index][i]=val
        else:
            set_data(row.DID_HORAS_SINCRONICAS,row.OFG_NUMERO,schedule_lvl,
                     schedule_carr,schedule_ofg, schedule_doc,
                     np.absolute(actual_populations[index]))
    return actual_populations

class GACustomize(GA):
    def random_mutation(self, offspring):
        for offspring_idx in range(offspring.shape[0]):
            create_schedule(offspring[offspring_idx].reshape(SHAPE))
        return offspring






inputs=[start_random_population().flatten() for i in range(5)]

GANN_customize = GACustomize(num_generations=500,
                                sol_per_pop=5,
                                num_parents_mating=2,
                                fitness_func=fitness_func,
                                num_genes=len(inputs),
                                mutation_type="random",
                                initial_population=inputs,
                                keep_parents=0,
                                save_best_solutions=True,
                                mutation_num_genes=15
                                )
GANN_customize.run()
```

There are a lot of undefined values ​​at the beginning of the code that I don't understand
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s76A.png) anyway colab showed it right away, underlined it in orange

I don't understand if I have to enter these values ​​or is it a library issue. (it didn't accept when I tried to enter a value either)